# processing natural language that descripe time frequency with R

Tags: r, natural-language, text-mining, frequency

I'm dealing with data that descripe onset frequency of a symptom. The text in each cell was not in the same format. For example:

```
"Pattern 1: 1~3/months, Pattern 2: 6 times per 3.5 month"                                                                                                                   
"4 to 5 times/day"                                                                                                                                                          
"10 times/day to 7-8 times every week"                                                                                                                                         
"varies (average 0-10 fits/month)"                                                                                                                                       
"1-2 times/month, but 2-3/week in recent 3 months\n"                                                                                                                     
"2-3/ 2 month"
```

What I'm trying to do is to generate the minimum and maximum frequency of each description for further statistical analysis. I can do this by regular expression, although it might not be very efficient. I'm very new to natural lauguage processing, is there a more efficient way to do this other than the regular expression way? Thanks!

According to my current(and very little) understanding, usually, there are many database to perform part of speech tagging and further syntactic analysis. In this case, however, I'm not sure if it's better to build my own database for such analysis. As I imagined, maybe there is a way to teach R to read the structure of the text, and maybe it will be easier to extract information afterward.

(Sorry about not being able to ask the question in a more specific way.)